# Заказал установку Firebase, и возник спорный вопрос

Tags: java, firebase

Всем привет,
У меня есть приложение, сам в java не разбираюсь, нашел на фрилансе человека. Взялся он устанавливать Firebase + FCM. Сам не смог установить, ибо там андроид студио просил мигрировать проект в AndroidX, и возникали проблемы с классами.

В общем фрилансер FCM установил отлично! Но FireBase не работает. Он говорит, что SDK установлена, а если установлена то должна работать! (Чтобы начать работать со StreamView, вам не потребуется ничего дополнительно устанавливать. Если вы правильно интегрировали Firebase SDK, система отчетов StreamView заработает автоматически. Проверить это можно с помощью инструмента DebugView.)

Я думал раздуплиться, и на сл.день начнет пахать (FB просило подождать 24 часа). Но чуда не стало, как только устанавливаешь приложение, вылазит только одно событие (first_open) и все.
Писал фрилансеру, говорит пиши в поддержку. Кого винить? Где косяк? Спасибо!

Comment: А какие ещё события вы ожидали увидеть? Возможно никаких событий не происходит вот вы их и не видите. Возможно, вам надо попросить человека сделать дополнительную работу и проставить в нужных местах регистрацию определённых событий.

Comment: хотя бы открытие плеера. Чтобы я видил сколько человек пользуется в день, помимо простой установки.

Comment: В таком случае надо составить разработчику ТЗ, т.к. такие события автоматически не собираются, надо вручную прописывать. Если не ошибаюсь, отслеживаться должны события перехода по активити, однако в наше время принято всего одну активити делать, засим события и не записываются, т.к. их нет.